# how to make a function separate from component angular

Tags: angular, function

I have one method in 2 components that does exact same logic. I want DRY code and make a function that does this. How can i make this method as separate function without making a service for it?

```
private compareWithMainDevice(): void {
    this.newBuildingStatisticsService.getMainDeviceAggregates(this.isDetail).subscribe(mainDeviceAggregates => {
      this.mainDeviceId = mainDeviceAggregates.device_id;
      const mainDev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainDeviceAggregates));
      const other = this.deviceAggregates;
      this.deviceAggregates = [mainDev, ...other];
      const devs = this.deviceAggregates.reduce((a, b) => {
        b.cost.forEach(({ value, timestamp }, i) => {
          if (mainDev.cost.length > i && a.cost[i].value > b.cost[i].value) {
            return a.cost[i].value -= value;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });

        return a;
      });

      this.deviceAggregates = [...other, devs];
      this.setChartOption(true);
    });
  }
```

I can't figure out how to pass the methods of component to this function.

Comment: Why are you against using a service, this is a text book use case for a service? I notice you are referencing 'this' in this function, which you stated is being used in two different components. You might consider combining the components if they are sharing multiple properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

But, in your case, if you want to share `compareWithMainDevice` method in two components without rewrite twice, you can create an abstract class with this method and your shared class properties (such as `mainDeviceId` by exemple)  into it. Then, each component will extends this class and they will have access to the method.